# Display orders placed before April 1, 2009. Write the query in two different ways

Tags: oracle

I did it the usual way. I don't get how to write the query in another way.

```
SELECT Order#, Shipdate 
FROM Orders
WHERE Shipdate < '01-APR-2009';
```

What can be the another way to write the same query?

Comment: The usual way would be to compare with a date (as shown in answers) not a string as you have done. How different do they have to be - with and without implicit conversions? Different date formats? Or something else? (And are you sure to want to be looking at ship date if the question refers to when the order was *placed*?)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what Utsav wrote (which is your query, with the needed correction so that the right-hand side of the inequality is a `DATE`), and this modification:

```
SELECT Order#, Shipdate FROM Orders 
 WHERE Shipdate < date '2009-04-01';
```

using the date literal syntax (`DATE <string>` where the string is enclosed in single-quotes and must be in the exact format `yyyy-mm-dd`, no deviation permitted; even the dashes must be dashes, not `/` or `.` or anything else).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming shipdate is `date` not `string`,

```
SELECT Order#, Shipdate FROM Orders 
 WHERE Shipdate < to_date('01-APR-2009','DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use negation, for logically the same query:

```
SELECT Order#, Shipdate 
FROM Orders
WHERE NOT Shipdate >= DATE '2009-04-01';
```

Or you could look at the date elements separately:

```
SELECT Order#, Shipdate 
FROM Orders
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM Shipdate) < 2009
OR (EXTRACT(year FROM Shipdate) = 2009
  AND EXTRACT(month FROM Shipdate) < 4);
```

though that sort of thing would prevent an index on the date column being used.